# Problem in Imperative way of calling apex through LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am new to Lightning Web Components. I created a component that searches for accounts. I used imperative method to call apex. I am having trouble understanding what is happening during imperative call due to `=>` operator. So I expanded the function by referring this [website](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc). But it gave me an error. How can I expand the function to make it more understandable?

> Previous Code

```html
@track accounts;
@track errorAccount;
findAccounts(){
        getAccList({
            name:this.searchKeyAcc
        }).then(result=>{
            this.accounts=result;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.errorAccount=error;
        })
    }
```

> New Code

```html
@track accounts;
@track errorAccount;
    findAccounts(){
        getAccList({
            name:this.searchKeyAcc
        }).then(function res(result){
            if(result){
                this.accounts=result;
            }
        })
        .catch(function err(error){
            if(error){
                this.errorAccount=error;
            }
        })
    }
```

> Error
>   [image: Error screenshot]

.

> JS code

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController1.getAccountList';


export default class AccountSearch extends LightningElement {
    @track searchKeyAcc;
    @track accounts;
    @track errorAccount;

    handleChangeAcc(event){

        this.searchKeyAcc = event.target.value;
    }
    findAccounts(){
        getAccList({
            name:this.searchKeyAcc
        }).then(result=>{
            this.accounts=result;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.errorAccount=error;
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring any other issues with the code, there is a fundamental difference between an arrow function and a regular function: the "this" instance (and other bindings).

An arrow function does NOT change the "this" binding, so in the original code, "this" refers to the component. However, when changing to use a regular function, "this" changes.

Take a look at the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information (and specifically the link to ["this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I get the impression that the function cannot be simplified.  I removed `this` keyword. It gives me an error saying the variable is not defined.

Comment: Keep the arrow functions. Otherwise you need to mess about explicitly binding the function to the component's "this". (As you discovered, you can't just drop the "this" reference. It is essential)